# Calculating vector so object is aligned with another object using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

Calculating vector so object is aligned with another object using geometry nodes.

I have several mesh Island objects that I'm trying to get lined up with a reference mesh island.  I'm using `Vector = Vector2 - Vector1` but for some reason it's not lining up.  There's something wrong with my calculations but I'm not sure what.

[image: img1]

**How can I align them so that each mesh island is aligned with the reference island mesh**.

**The alignment is off see red arrow.**

[image: img2]

Animated mesh islands that are off.
[image: ani1]

**Please note the reference mesh island can be any island.**

The mesh islands should align with the X-axis see image below **see blue circles**.

[image: img align]
See Blend file below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at what you're aligning to, the result of the top *Attribute Statistic: Min* is $2.27403$.

[image]

This is because you're aligning to an **Edge** position. The edge position is the position of its center. Since the bottom *Stat* node also operates in the Edge dimension, you're effectively aligning the center of one edge to the center of another edge:

[image]

To solve your [Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), switch "Edge" domain to "Point" in both "Attribute Statistic" nodes.

Your [X solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) seems to be this:

[image]

[image]